# How to mirror only a section of a website?

Tags: wget, mirror

I cannot get wget to mirror a section of a website (a folder path below root) - it only seems to work from the website homepage.

I've tried many options - here is one example

```
wget -rkp -l3 -np  http://somewebsite/subpath/down/here/
```

While I only want to mirror the content links below that URL - I also need to download all the page assets which are not in that path.

It seems to work fine for the homepage (`/`) but I can't get it going for any sub folders.

Answer (score 89):

Use the `--mirror` (`-m`) and `--no-parent` (`-np`) options, plus a few of cool ones, like in this example:

```
wget --mirror --page-requisites --adjust-extension --no-parent --convert-links
     --directory-prefix=sousers http://stackoverflow.com/users
```

Comment: To save anyone else searching the wget manual, -p is --page-requisites and -P is --directory-prefix

Comment: Just as a note for others who might bump into this issue where the most commonly downloaded wget binary for Windows 7 seems to be gnuwin32 packages from sourceforge.net, but those are wget-1.11 which do not have the --adjust-extension functionality. It was apparently added only in wget-1.12. So Windows 7 users can get a much newer and self-contained binary from here instead (http://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/)

Answer (score 19):

I usually use:

```
wget -m -np -p $url
```

Comment: `-p` to download everything required to display a page is useful. Does that override `-np` for those elements necessary to display a page?

Comment: For informational purposes only: `-m` = mirror, `-np` = no parent (don't retrieve files higher up in the hierarchy when recursing), `-p` = page requisites or all items necessary to appropriately display the web page.

Answer (score 3):

I use pavuk to accomplish mirrors, as it seemed much better for this purpose just from the beginning. You can use something like this:

```
/usr/bin/pavuk -enable_js -fnrules F '*.php?*' '%o.php' -tr_str_str '?' '_questionmark_' \
               -norobots -dont_limit_inlines -dont_leave_dir \
               http://www.example.com/some_directory/ >OUT 2>ERR
```

Answer (score 2):

For my use case the no parent option didn't quite work.

I was trying to mirror `https://www.example.com/section` and URLs under it like `https://www.example.com/section/subsection`. This can't be done with `--no-parent` because if you start at `/section` then it'll download the entire site if you start at `/section/` then the site redirects to `/section` and now it's at parent so wget stops. Fun.

Instead, I am using `--acept-regex 'https://www.example.com/(section|assets/).*'`. This worked. (Although it would download `sectionfoobar` but this was acceptable for me and now we are wandering into regexp territory which is amply covered elsewhere on SO.)

Answer (score 0):

Check out archivebox.io, it's an open-source, self-hosted tool that creates a local, static, browsable HTML clone of websites (it saves HTML, JS, media files, PDFs, screenshot, static assets and more).

By default, it only archives the URL you specify, but we're adding a `--depth=n` flag soon that will let you recursively archive links from the given URL.